# Testing localStorage using mocks or spies in Angular 7 Applications using latest jest setup

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jestjs

I am trying to unit test my **Angular 7** application using ***jest*** and want to test if a method is called by setting localStorage. But I understand that setting the real localStorage is not ideal when testing, hence have to use *mocks* or *spies*. Since I'm new to unit-testing, I would like to know if there is a better method to test this and if my approach is correct.

I'm mainly asking this again here is because of [this](https://github.com/clarkbw/jest-localstorage-mock/issues/106) issue. It says jest now provides localStorage support out of the box. So, in the following methodology, is the localStorage mocked automatically or is my approach wrong?

#### login.component.spec.ts

```js
    test('Call onSubmit() when localStorage is set', () => {
        const mockSubmit = jest.spyOn(component, 'onSubmit');
        localStorage.setItem('auth', 'abcd');
        component.ngOnInit();

        expect(mockSubmit).toBeCalled();
    });
```

---

#### login.component.ts

```js
    ngOnInit(): void {
        if (localStorage.getItem('auth') !== null) {

            this.onSubmit();
        }
    }
```

Mocking and Spying in ***jest*** is a bit confusing for me, so any advice or help is appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

It's a bad practice to work with localStorage in your components, better move it logic to separate service (for example: AuthService ), and after that in your tests you can spyOn service methods and check that they `toHaveBeenCalled`

Comment: Ya but it is not possible for me to change the source code. So I'm asking whether the above implementation auto mocks the localstorage or do I have to manually mock it? And if so how? because the above mentioned repo issue says now its usage comes out of the box. thanks